# How to create VB loop: foreach file with prefix in directory?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have to use vb for powerpoint macros. I am stuck figuring out how to add a prefix with vb wildcard in the foreach.

I need it to say foreach file in C:/ with prefix "customslide". The slides will be enumerated 0-infinite. Jpg format if it matters. I suspect it will add alphanumerically but if not please advise how to remedy.

Even a link to proper tutorial is appreciated.

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim fil As File

For Each fil In fso.GetFolder("C:\").Files
  Debug.Print fil.Name
Next
```

I have code in place for adding slide to my presentation, but only by specific filename so for example print file name is in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
For Each fil In fso.GetFolder("C:\*customslide*").Files
  Debug.Print fil.Name
Next
```

Comment: Oh haha. Didnt think itd be so simple. Thank you very much!